# Can we show alert when application gets crash in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to check when application gets crash i want show one alert view instead of closing app. please tell me if any solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use error handling methods @try ,catch  in catch block u can show error in alertView

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                  initWithTitle:@"Crashing....."
                  message:@"Error is"
                  delegate:self
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK"];
```

Comment: You cannot foresee where your app is going to crash

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.but you can catch the exception using **uncaughtexceptionhandler** and write to disk and read it when next time opened and show the alert.

But you can't stop the crashing application and show the alert

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception by the following code:

Add the following line at the bottom of - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in you `AppDelegate.m` :

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Add the following method to your `AppDelegate.m` :

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);

   // do your handling
}
```

**You can read the crash logs from here and save them on the disk. But you cannot present an alert here.**